# Disable the overlay scrollbar ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have just installed the ubuntu on my machine, I heard every thing is possible with linux,

I found the scrollbar is very complex, and hard to use,

Is there is any way to disable it? and put it as in normal look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get back overlay bar, enter following command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

Enter following command in terminal to disable overlay scrollbar:

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode
```

or you can visit [Linuxicle](http://linuxicle.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-desable-overlay-scrollbar-on.html).